# Ambiguous interface

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am  getting the following error when trying to compile my Haskel code

```
Main.hs:11:1: error:
    Ambiguous interface for ‘Data.Matrix’:
      it was found in multiple packages: matrices-0.4.4 matrix-0.3.5.0
```

How do I solve this. I cannot use hide since it is the whole interface that is abiguous.

Comment: What exactly is the code that causes this error? We can't solve your problem if you don't describe it fully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [the `PackageImports` language extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.2/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#package-qualified-imports), you can qualify an import with a particular package:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PackageImports #-}
import "matrix" Data.Matrix
```

However, as the documentation suggests, it’s not always a great idea. There are other ways to solve the problem, including [renaming modules from particular packages using GHC flags](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.2/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html#package-thinning-and-renaming). For example, you could change `Data.Matrix` from `matrix` to a different name with the following GHC options:

```
-package "matrix (Data.Matrix as Data.OtherMatrix)"
```

You may choose the option that works best for you, depending on the specifics and your needs.

Comment: There's a much simpler solution which I think is worth mentioning: use a `.cabal` file and don't depend on both `matrices` and `matrix` in it. It seems unlikely that both packages are really needed in a single application/library.

Comment: @DanielWagner I considered mentioning that, but I assumed the OP needed both packages, so that wasn’t an option. In general, though, yes, usually only one of the packages will be visible, resolving the ambiguity.